terragrunt is not generating backend or provider file
I have a following folder structure.  if I navigate to test_include/first_level folder and run terragrunt init or plan. it doesn't create an backend.tf or provider.tf file. and local backend is being used.
Do i need to run terragrunt init from root folder first?
├── terragrunt.hcl
├── test_include
│   ├── first_level
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── terragrunt.hcl

terragurnt.hcl

remote_state {
  backend = "gcs"

  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }

  config = {
    project  = "google-project-1"
    location = "northamerica-northeast1"
    bucket   = "tfstate-123"
    prefix   = "include_demo/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"

    gcs_bucket_labels = {
      owner = "terragrunt_state"
      name  = "terraform_state_storage"
    }
  }
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"

  contents = <<EOF
   provider "google" {
      region = "northamerica-northeast1"
      # version = "5.32.0"
    }
  EOF
}


test_include/terragrunt.hcl
inputs = {
  account = "account"
}

test_include/first_level/terragrunt.hcl
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

terraform {
  source = "../../module/"
}

inputs = {
  env  = "env"
  name = "gaurang"
}




find_in_parent_folders() searches up the directory tree from the
current terragrunt.hcl file and returns the absolute path to the first
terragrunt.hcl in a parent folder or exit with an error if no such
file is found.

Therefore the first terragrunt.hcl will be used and it will never reach the root terragrunt.hcl. There are multiple solutions for this:
First Solution
The content of test_include/terragrunt.hcl should be moved to test_include/first_level/terragrunt.hcl, and test_include/terragrunt.hcl should be removed. Then we have:
test_include/first_level/terragrunt.hcl
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

terraform {
  source = "../../module/"
}

inputs = {
  env  = "env"
  name = "gaurang"
  account = "account"
}

test_include/terragrunt.hcl
--removed
Second Solution
You can use get_path_to_repo_root if the root terragrunt.hcl is in the root of your git repository:
test_include/first_level/terragrunt.hcl
include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}

include "veryroot" {
  path = "${get_path_to_repo_root()}/terragrunt.hcl"
}

terraform {
  source = "../../module/"
}

inputs = {
  env  = "env"
  name = "gaurang"
}

Third Solution
Using optional_var_files or required_var_files function. Here is an example.
